# How to reset the value of a double, int, float etc after an "Incorrect" input by the user

Tags: java, variables, integer, double, reset

My question is in relation to my line of code resembling an ATM. The current balance being `10000`, What i have written shows a message to the user that if they withdraw over the given balance that it is `Insufficient balance`. However the balance continues to change thus when `Inquiring balance` the balance is now < the allowed balance. My question is how should i go about resetting the double value for the balance when the `Insufficient balance` message is shown to the user?

Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class app {
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    long pin = 2927942074l;
    double balance = 10000.0;
    int attempts = 3;

    System.out.println("Please enter your pin.");

    while (attempts > 0) {
    Scanner keyboardpin = new Scanner(System.in);
    long input = keyboardpin.nextLong();

    if (input == pin) {
          System.out.println("Correct");
          System.out.println("Welcome to your ATM");
        while (true) { // Keep printing your options unless "Quit" is chosen

          int a = 1;
          int b = 2;
          int c = 3;
          int d = 0;

            System.out.println(a + " - Inquire Balance");
            System.out.println(b + " - Withdraw");
            System.out.println(c + " - Deposit");
            System.out.println(d + " - Quit");
            System.out.println("Please select what you want to do.");

          Scanner menuselect = new Scanner(System.in);
          int menuinput = menuselect.nextInt();

          if (menuinput == a) {
              System.out.println(balance);
              continue;
          }
          if (menuinput == b) {
            System.out.println("Please enter a withdrawal amount.");
          Scanner withdrawamount = new Scanner(System.in);
          double withdrawbalace = withdrawamount.nextDouble();
          balance = (balance - withdrawbalace);
          if (withdrawbalace > balance)
            System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
          if (withdrawbalace <= balance)
            System.out.println("Youre new balance is " + balance);
          }
          if (menuinput == c) {

          }
          if (menuinput == d) {
              break;
          }
      if (attempts == 0) {
          System.out.println("Maximum number of attempts exceeded");
          }
        }
      } else {
      System.out.println("Wrong");
      attempts--;
      System.out.println("You have " + attempts + " attempts remaining.");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just check whether the user has enough balance before subtracting the amount.

```
if (menuinput == b) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a withdrawal amount.");
    Scanner withdrawamount = new Scanner(System.in);
    double withdrawbalace = withdrawamount.nextDouble();
    if (withdrawbalace > balance)
        System.out.println("Insufficient balance");
    if (withdrawbalace <= balance)
        balance = (balance - withdrawbalace);
        System.out.println("Youre new balance is " + balance);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem has been solved in the previous answer, but your code logic has some errors. I have fixed it for you.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

class app {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final long pin = 2927942074L;
        double balance = 10000.0;
        int attempts = 3;

        System.out.println("Please enter your pin.");
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        while (attempts > 0) {
            long input = keyboard.nextLong();

            if (input == pin) {
                System.out.println("Correct");
                System.out.println("Welcome to your ATM");

                // Keep printing your options unless "Quit" is chosen
                while (true) {
                    int a = 1;
                    int b = 2;
                    int c = 3;
                    int d = 0;

                    System.out.println(a + " - Inquire Balance");
                    System.out.println(b + " - Withdraw");
                    System.out.println(c + " - Deposit");
                    System.out.println(d + " - Quit");
                    System.out.println("Please select what you want to do.");

                    int menuInput = keyboard.nextInt();

                    if (menuInput == a) {
                        System.out.println(balance);

                    } else if (menuInput == b) {
                        System.out.println("Please enter a withdrawal amount.");
                        double withdrawBalance = keyboard.nextDouble();

                        if (balance >= withdrawBalance) {
                            balance -= withdrawBalance;
                            System.out.println("Your new balance is " + balance);
                        } else System.out.println("Insufficient balance");

                    } else if (menuInput == c) {
                        // Deposit code here
                    } else if (menuInput == d) break;
                }

            } else {
                attempts--;

                if (attempts == 0) {
                    System.out.println("Maximum number of attempts exceeded");
                    break;
                }
                System.out.println("Wrong");
                System.out.println("You have " + attempts + " attempts remaining.");
            }
        }
        keyboard.close();
    }
}
```

And here are some tips...

1. Try to choose meaningful variable names.
2. If the variable has a constant value make it `final`
3. If the variable name consists of two, or more, words capitalize the first letter of the second word (eg. `menuInput`)
4. If you check the same condition for different cases you can use `switch` or `if`, `else if`, `else`
5. Never forget to close the objects you used to release memory

Good Luck